# Как передать ссылку на файл в метод класса

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Start();
        string path = @"C:\SomeDir";
        string subpath = @"program\avalon";
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        if (!dirInfo.Exists)
        {
            dirInfo.Create();
        }
        dirInfo.CreateSubdirectory(subpath);
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }



        public Person(string fullName, int age, string sex, DateTime date)
        {
            FullName = fullName;
            Age = age;
            Gender = sex;
            Date = date;

        }

        public Person()
        {
        }
        public virtual void Find()
        {
            string a = FullName + Age + "\n" + Gender + "\n" + Date;
            string b = "Людину яку ви шукаєте";
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(a, b);
            }
            //MessageBox.Show(a, b);
        }
    }
```

Тут нужно чтобы метод Find вместо MassageBox записал значения в файл C:\SomeDir\program\avalon

```
//Исправил
public virtual void Find(string path)
        {
            string a = FullName + Age + "\n" + Gender + "\n" + Date;
            string b = "Людину яку ви шукаєте";
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(a, b);
            }
            //MessageBox.Show(a, b);
        }
```

Comment: Либо делайте переменную класса, которая будет доступна во всем классе; либо передавайте через аргумент (`Find(string path) { ... }`  `Person.Find("С:\")`). Все зависит от задач, ибо в нормальном проекте, используются правила S.O.L.I.D., по которым методы и классы например, должны выполнять одну задачу (SRP), а у вас получается метод `Find` и ищет, и записывает в файл (2 задачи), а если еще и `MessageBox`, то будет 3 (+вывод на экран). По нормальному у вас в методе должен быть лишь поиск нужного, а затем возврат наружу (условно `string Find(string name) { return ...; }` `var name = Find("..")`)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Так правильно? Я исправил

Comment: Повторю, зависит от задач. Я не знаю, что вы делаете, что должен этот метод делать также не знаю. Но как вариант, да, вы передаете таким образом строку (или нужный тип) в метод. И да, не исправляйте оригинальный вопрос, дополняйте его, ибо вот как будущим читателям вам помогать, если в коде уже нет "ошибки"?